# Email notification when static website hosted on S3 bucket crashes on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have hosted the static website on AWS s3, and I want to get notified whenever the site crashes or is unable to be displayed on the website link,
I tried this with website hosted on Ec2 instance and it worked fine but it's giving hard time on s3 hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable server access logging, and collect the logs for the website access on S3.
Server access logging provides detailed records for the requests that are made to a bucket. Server access logs are useful for many applications. For example, access log information can be useful in security and access audits. It can also help you learn about your customer base and understand your Amazon S3 bill.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Make sure to configure CloudTrail as well, since events are based on the CloudTrail mechanism.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html

The logs are collected on another S3 bucket. You can configure this bucket to alert you on specific logs (trigger and event), through the EventBridge service.
For example, you can sent all logs to CloudWatch and create an advanced alarm based on the logs in CloudWatch.